# Acceder al contenido de una tabla añadida con JOIN SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Estoy haciendo una API utilizando Flask y SQLAlchemy, pero estoy teniendo varios problemas a la hora de acceder a los datos de tablas.

Esta es la consulta que estoy realizando:

```
projects = Project.query.join(ProjectStatus, Project.id_project == ProjectStatus.project_id).join(InstallationStatus, InstallationStatus.id_status == ProjectStatus.status_id).all()
```

Y de esta forma estoy recogiendo los datos

```
response = []
    for project in projects:
        data = {
            "id_project": project.id_project,
            "installation_name": project.installation_name,
            "scheduled_installation_date": project.scheduled_installation_date,
            "date_installation_ended": project.date_installation_ended,
            "mobile_phone": project.mobile_phone,
            "delivery_point_postal_code": project.delivery_point_postal_code,
            "delivery_point_latitude": project.delivery_point_latitude,
            "delivery_point_longitude": project.delivery_point_longitude,
            "power_installed": project.power_installed,
            "status_id": project.project_status.status_id if project.project_status else '',
            "name_status": project.installation_status.name_status if project.installation_status else '',
            "created_by": project.project_status.created_by if project.project_status else ''
        }
        response.append(data)
```

El error que me esta dando es que no existe el atributo `project_status` en la tabla `Project`:

```
'Project' object has no attribute 'project_status'
```

Estos son los modelos que he creado:

```
class Project(db.Model):
    id_project = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    installation_name = db.Column(db.String(200))
    scheduled_installation_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    date_installation_ended = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    mobile_phone = db.Column(db.String(100))
    delivery_point_postal_code = db.Column(db.String(200))
    delivery_point_latitude = db.Column(db.Double)
    delivery_point_longitude = db.Column(db.Double)
    power_installed = db.Column(db.Double)
    created_at = db.Column(db.Date)
    updated_at = db.Column(db.Date)
    deleted_at = db.Column(db.Date)



class InstallationStatus(db.Model):
    id_status = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name_status = db.Column(db.String(50))
    description = db.Column(db.String(200))
    color = db.Column(db.String(20))



class ProjectStatus(db.Model):
    id_project_status = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    project_id = db.Column(db.String(100), db.ForeignKey(
        'project.id_project'), nullable=False)
    status_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'installationstatus.id_status'), nullable=False)
    created_by = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'username.id_user'), nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

La lista devuelta por el query no solo tiene proyectos, sino status de proyecto y status de instalación relacionados, en este caso.

Estas entidades están en el orden que las has ido añadiendo al join.

Por tanto, para recorrerla, podrías hacer algo como:

```
results = session.query(Project).join(ProjectStatus, Project.id_project == ProjectStatus.project_id).join(InstallationStatus, InstallationStatus.id_status == ProjectStatus.status_id).all()

for project, projectStatus, installationStatus in results:
    blah(blah)
```